# RESTful API Design : modeling relationships

Tags: rest, api

I have a two models, employee and tasks.
empid and taskid are primary keys of both models
I want to design a RESTful API to model this relationship.

I have thought of the following design:

```
hostname/task GET : get all tasks
hostname/task POST : post a tasks
hostname/task/:taskid GET : get a certain task
hostname/task/:taskid DELETE :  delete a certain task
hostname/task/:taskid PATCH :  update a certain task
```

but my problem is that every task is bound to an employee ID and i want this to be represented.

so should i do this

```
hostname/task/:empid GET : all tasks for a certain ID
hostname/task/:empid/taskid DELETE/PATCH/GET : delete/update or retrieve for a certain employees task
```

I am not getting how to model this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the query. If you want to be explicit about the relation, you could (and should, IMO) have the following endpoints:

```
GET    /employees/:empid/tasks
DELETE /employees/:empid/tasks/:taskid
```

However, if you need to be able to query all tasks without taking the employee into consideration, as an API Consumer, I'd expect to have the same methods as on the employee-task endpoints, i.e.

```
GET    /tasks
DELETE /tasks/:taskid
```

You could write some authorization logic to decide whether the consumer has the proper permissions to delete tasks on a "global" level without specifying the employee.

Comment: Don't mix singular and plural! http://apigee.com/about/blog/technology/restful-api-design-plural-nouns-and-concrete-names

Comment: @Dencker : hey, Thanks for the response.

I had one more question to your answer

GET    /employees/:empid/tasks 


can i pass the empid as a parameter instead of explicitly mentioning it in the URI?

Comment: You _can_, but you shouldn't. That would go against the relation pattern. If you want to show tasks belonging to a specific employee, you should follow the `/employees/:id/tasks/:id` pattern. If you insist on using query parameters, it would be legitimate to design some kind of search endpoint, allowing you to do fx. `/tasks/search?employee_id[in]=1,7,39` or simply `/tasks/search?employee_id=7`, allowing you to search on other fields as well: `/tasks/search?employee_id=7&importance=urgent`, but that endpoint should be readonly/non-destructive (i.e. no `DELETE` operations)

Comment: Np @SuyashThite - happy coding!